# Payflow to create Recurring Payment with PayPal account

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing, payflowpro, payflowlink

I am using payflow link hosted checkout pages and creating recurring profile. It is working if user pay with credit card and using pnref to create recurring profile. But it is not working if user make payment using paypal account. And getting error code 23 and error “Invalid account number” .

Please advice me for the same.

Comment: Invalid account number means the credit card information is incorrect or not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Payflow link only allow the user to submit Recurring Billing with Credit Card as the funding source. If you wish to have a choice of payment with PayPal account, you probably want to consider Payflow Pro.